# Spark generate a list of column names that contains(SQL LIKE) a string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This one below is a simple syntax to search for a string in a particular column uisng SQL Like functionality.

```
val dfx = df.filter($"name".like(s"%${productName}%"))
```

The questions is How do I grab **each and every column NAME** that contained the particular string in its VALUES and generate a new column with a list of those "column names" for every row.

So far this is the approach I took but stuck as I cant use spark-sql "Like" function inside a UDF.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

import spark.implicits._
val df1 = Seq(
  (0, "mango", "man", "dit"), 
  (1, "i-man", "man2", "mane"),
  (2, "iman", "mango", "ho"),
  (3, "dim",  "kim", "sim")
).toDF("id", "col1", "col2", "col3")

val df2 = df1.columns.foldLeft(df1) {
  (acc: DataFrame, colName: String) =>
    acc.withColumn(colName, concat(lit(colName + "="), col(colName)))
}

val df3 = df2.withColumn("merged_cols", split(concat_ws("X",  df2.columns.map(c=> col(c)):_*), "X"))
```

Here is a sample output. **Note** that here there are only 3 columns but in the real job I'll be reading multiple tables which can contain dynamic number of columns.

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|id  |   col1|  col2|  col3|      merged_cols
+--------------------------------------------+
  0  |  mango| man  |  dit | col1, col2
  1  |  i-man| man2 | mane | col1, col2, col3
  2  |  iman | mango| ho   | col1, col2
  3  |   dim |  kim |   sim| 
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a `foldLeft` over the columns together with `when` and `otherwise`:

```
val e = "%man%"

val df2 = df1.columns.foldLeft(df.withColumn("merged_cols", lit(""))){(df, c) => 
    df.withColumn("merged_cols", when(col(c).like(e), concat($"merged_cols", lit(s"$c,"))).otherwise($"merged_cols"))}
  .withColumn("merged_cols", expr("substring(merged_cols, 1, length(merged_cols)-1)"))
```

All columns that satisfies the condition `e` will be appended to the string in the `merged_cols` column. Note that the column must exist for the first append to work so it is added (containing an empty string) to the dataframe when sent into the `foldLeft`.

The last row in the code simply removes the extra `,` that is added in the end. If you want the result as an array instead, simply adding `.withColumn("merged_cols", split($"merged_cols", ","))` would work.

---

An alternative appraoch is to instead use an `UDF`. This could be preferred when dealing with many columns since `foldLeft` will create multiple dataframe copies. Here regex is used (not the SQL like since that operates on whole columns).

```
val e = ".*man.*"

val concat_cols = udf((vals: Seq[String], names: Seq[String]) => {
  vals.zip(names).filter{case (v, n) => v.matches(e)}.map(_._2)
})

val df2 = df.withColumn("merged_cols", concat_cols(array(df.columns.map(col(_)): _*), typedLit(df.columns.toSeq)))
```

**Note**: `typedLit` can be used in Spark versions 2.2+, when using older versions use `array(df.columns.map(lit(_)): _*)` instead.

Comment: there is an issue, it works with 3 columns not with 18! foldLeft can't be parallelized on Spark/scala and the driver dies even with just 1 row of 18 columns.

Comment: @data-maniac: I did some tests and while it worked with 18 and more columns when I ran locally it was very slow. I added an alternative approach using an udf above that should be better when using more columns.